# multiple parameters into sql select 'in' statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a dynamic built query using the 'IN' clause, but really need to select for two parameters, and cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

```
$selectSql= "SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE name IN(";

foreach ($groupsArray as $group => $row){

  $selectSql .= "'".$row['name']."'".",";

}  
$selectSql = rtrim($selectSql, ',');
$selectSql .= ")";
```

Really, the query needs to look something like:

```
$selectSql= "SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE name and type IN(;
```

How would I go about doing this?

Sincere thanks for any help! it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: now what is your present output?

Comment: What you are doing has nothing to do with prepared statement. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try `implode()`

```
foreach ($groupsArray as $group => $row ){
  $name[]= "'".$row['name']."'";
  $type[] = "'".$row['type']."'";
}  
$selectSql= "SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE name IN(".implode(',',$name).") and type IN(".implode(',',$type).")";
```

Answer (score 2):

I also support `implode()` but done in a slightly different way:

```
$name = array();
$type = array();
foreach ($groupsArray as $group => $row ) {
  $name[] = $row['name'];
  $type[] = $row['type'];
}

$selectSql= "SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE name IN ('". implode("' ,'", $name) ."') and type IN ('". implode("', '", $type). "')";
```

In this way you do not have to change the array to insert the `'` to each item because it is done by implode.

I did not understand well what he's like your array, but you may even direct access `$groupsArray` items without creating `$name` and `$type`.